# Multi-dimensional arrays in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am preparing for OCAJP exam, I got a problem with the multi-dimensional arrays in java. After go through a video tutorial on YouTube, I think I got an idea about how it works.  It says the following statement creates two double dimensional arrays and one array to hold both arrays. Hence it is a three dimensional array.

```
int arr[][][] = new int[2][4][3];
```

So I want to get confirmed, that if I want a five dimensional array, this statement would do it.

```
 int arr[][][] = new int[4][4][3];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to visualise it geometrically.

- A 1-dimensional array is just a list: `new int[2]`
- A 2-dimensional array is a rectangular grid (or a list of lists): `new int[2][3]`
- A 3-dimensional array is a cuboid (or a list of rectangles, or a list
  of lists of lists): `new int[2][3][4]`

After this it gets harder, but :

- a 4D array is a list of cuboids (a list
  of lists of lists of lists) `new int[2][3][4][5]`
- a 5D array is a grid of cuboids (a list
  of lists of lists of lists of lists): `new int[2][3][4][5][6]`

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[][][] = new int[4][4][3];
```

Is still a 3 dimensional array.

A 5 dimensional array looks like

```
 int arr[][][][][] = new int[4][4][3][4][3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[][][][][] = new int[4][4][3][X][X];
```

x can be any number. this is a 5 dimentional array.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a cube.

```
int arr[][][] = new int[2][4][3];
```

Here you have 2 slices of an array of 4x3.

```
int arr[][][] = new int[4][4][3];
```

With this, you have 4 slices of an array of 4x3.

So, it stills a three dimensional array.
However, you can save 4 different two dimensional arrays there.

Answer (score 0):

every time you add a new dimension the number of elements grow exponentially. int[4][4][3] means a 3-dimensions array with 4*4*3=48 elements. to create a 5-dimension array add 2 more square-brackets int[2][2][2][2][2] which is an array with 2^5 elements(2*2*2*2*2)