# is it possible for 2 dimension array store one integer and one double?

Tags: java

### So, if my values are:

123, 12.34

234, 23.34

345, 45.67

etc. like this,is it possible to use 2 dimension array to set up those values?

Comment: just use a `double[][]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

Technically you cannot define different static type per array dimension. So you cannot mix an `int` column with a `double` column. Even for objects you cannot mix an `Integer` column with a `Double` column.

If you just need primitives you can use `double[][]` as a double can represent all 32-bit integers (see [Representing integers in doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759201/representing-integers-in-doubles)). But technically the array is all-doubles: nothing would prevent you from storing a value like `3.14` in the the first column.

For objects, you can use a common base type (if one exists). For your particular use case, all numerical types extend `java.lang.Number` therefore this works:

```
    @Test
    public void testMixedNumbersArray() {
        Number[][] array = new Number[3][2];
        array[0][0] = 123; array[0][1] = 12.34;
        array[1][0] = 234; array[1][1] = 23.34;
        array[2][0] = 345; array[2][1] = 45.67;
        for (Number[] x : array) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
        }
    }

// outputs:
// [123, 12.34]
// [234, 23.34]
// [345, 45.67]
```

Keep in mind that this will actually allow you to also mix Float, Short, ...or even BigDecimal values in this array, as well as allow `null` values.

Therefore, if you need tight control over the data type, an option would be to create a custom class that encapsulates two separate arrays of the appropriate type:

```
public class MyArray {
    int[] col1;
    double[] col2;

    public MyArray(int size) {
        col1 = new int[size];
        col2 = new double[size];
    }
    // ... add get/set methods as needed, e.g.

    public void setCol1(int pos, int value) {
        col1[pos] = value;
    }

    public void setCol2(int pos, double value) {
        col2[pos] = value;
    }
}
```

One last thing to keep in mind is that Java multi-dimensional arrays are "arrays of arrays" (see [Multi-dimensional arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597504/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-java)). This is why there is only a single type: that of the inner-most array. All other dimensions are just levels of indirection (arrays of arrays) on the way to the target array instance.